# Vertical section position

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages

My page is in Arabic, by default the vertical section is on the left of the page.

Can I change the position of the vertical section to the right of the page.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Unfortunately, you cannot change the position of vertical section on modern pages.

By default, vertical sections are available only on the right side of the page. But as you are using Arabic language (right to left), vertical section will be shown on left side only and you cannot change this behavior as there are no options available in section settings.

Only option you have is, move vertical section to go to the top or bottom of your page when your browser window is condensed to a smaller size:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Add a vertical section](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899)

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome @MBIT!